# How to upgrade Redhat 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: rhel, upgrade

We have two server running on RHEL 5.5. Now we have to upgrade it to 5.6

What are the steps to upgrade it and also the prerequisites

Answer (score 3):

Some sources say to:

> Aquire the 5.6 repository information from the RedHat website, then do
>
> ```
> # yum update
> ```

Although the RHEL documentation, albeit not very clear, says to use the CD/installer and select the "upgrade" option. See [Common Tasks](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/pt-common-info.html) (chapter 24).

Comment: I'm pretty sure (though not absolutely certain) that the RH docs you point to are only for major releases (4 to 5, 5 to 6), not for minor release (5.5 to 5.6). But can't really find anything useful either.

Comment: More than likely, although there really isn't a lot of information on the subject around. I think the better option would have to be the first, but some sources i've read also say that RHEL doesn't have yum installed by default and it would require CentOS repos etc.

Comment: Yum's standard in RHEL5 and above (https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/c1-yum.html) AFAIK.

Comment: Well then I guess the first part of the answer was correct :p

Comment: I tried to find the Redhat 5.6  repository but couldn't find it. And there is no information for Upgrading to minor releases.

Comment: Will it be possible to Upgrade if i copy the RPMs of 5.6 and create a repository for them. And then I use Yum Update command to update?????

Comment: I believe the repos for 5.5 and 5.6 would be the same, you just need to modify the version parameters in the relevant repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/, for example on CentOS **`mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os`** would become **`mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5.6&arch=x86_64&repo=os`**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**CentOS 5.6 Release-Notes - Known Issues**](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS5.6#head-60758eb5ab66c94f98fda0383fa8c7a8b97b9c53). The same should be true for RHEL 5.6.

Since you are upgrading from 5.5 (and NOT an earlier version) to 5.6
`yum update` after

- Applying the most recent 5.5 patches
- Changing of the 5.5 repositories to the 5.6 repositories

Should be enough. The described iSCSI-client-bug might apply to you.